# How to pass a dictionary in DestroyAPI SUccess MEssage

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class ExampleDestroyView(DestroyAPIView):

    serializer_class = PetSerializer
    queryset = Pet.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "object_id"
    def perform_destroy(self, instance):
        self.data = {}
        self.data['status'] = True
        approval()
        self.data['msg'] = "It removed"
        return self.data
```

Here is my Sample Class ..... In this I need to Delete an objet.... It's deleting

But I am unable to pass the following Dict As an OutPut

How can I pass the status and a message in a dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the **`destroy(...)`** method

```
from rest_framework.generics import DestroyAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


class ExampleDestroyView(DestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = PetSerializer

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        data = self.perform_destroy(instance)
        return Response(data=data, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Comment: IN this self.perfome_destroy is the function thatI used in my sample code ?

Comment: Or default code ?
Becuae I need to override the perform_destroy function

Comment: Just use this answer as is... The only thing you need to customize is the **`data`** dictionary

Comment: Why do you need to override the **``perform_destroy()`** method?

Comment: Coz it's not a normal delete

Inside the perform _destroy() I am calling another functuon 

It's for approval

Comment: Oke.. that seems fine, I think

Comment: @Arkkal Abu Just Check it

Answer (score -2):

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from snippets.models import Snippet
from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def snippet_list(request):
    """
    List all code snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: What about adding a few words of explanation on how this code is supposed to solve the problem described in the question ? Keep in mind that answers that contain an explanation are considered to be of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.